# How to do i add a 24 hour delay if a condition is met?

Tags: c#, date, unity-game-engine, time

In my game, i am trying to make a function that if the player gets more than 10 stars, the star spawner would not spawn stars for the next 24 hours. How do i go about this when i cannot use the unity systems function without affecting Random fucntion that spawns the star?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Timers;

public class StarSpawner : MonoBehaviour   {
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
public GameObject[] blockPrefab;

public float timeBetweenWaves = 1f;

private float timeToSpawn = 2f;



// Start is called before the first frame update
void Spawn()
{
Instantiate(blockPrefab[Random.Range(0, blockPrefab.Length)], spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, 
spawnPoints.Length)]);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
if (Time.time >= timeToSpawn)
{
    Spawn();
    timeToSpawn = Time.time + timeBetweenWaves;
}
}
```

Comment: [This is the same as your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106941/how-to-use-date-in-unity-c-sharp#comment125696313_71106941) on your other account.

Comment: What I don't get: you post a question, people interact with it, you don't edit it or improve it, or interact with people who could help you. Instead, you post basically the exact same question again from a different account without explaining why the advice you received doesn't work for you. You don't even address why you posted it a second time. Why is that?

Comment: i am so sorry. From my other account i couldn't respond to the question because it was closed by stackoverflow and i couldn't reask it again so i decided to ask it again with a new accunt. I tried what you said but using systems doesnot allow me to use random again

Comment: I'm not 100% understanding from your code, but it sounds like you want to have `Spawn` 
 do multiple things and only one should be limited to a 24-hour period. It seems like you have something like `if (24hourPeriodElapsed) { Spawn(); }` rather than having `Spawn() { if (someRandomCondition && 24hourPeriodElapsed) { } }`.

Comment: What is wrong with the comments you already received on the other duplicate question?

Comment: @Llama The question was closed and i could not ask another question on the same account. I tried what you said but if i use using systems, i cannot spawn the powerups randomly again

Comment: @Llama The spawn only spawns the powerup(star) by choosing one random point to spawn the object at a particular time frame(the way i have set it, choose a ranfdom spawn point to spawn one star after 2 seconds) so i want something like if ( staramount >= 10){ stars should stop spawning for 24 hours) and after 24 hours the spawn should continue again

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem and then "saved" the current time data, i.e. date and time in PlayerPrefs. I then queried at certain intervals to see if the saved time was longer than the time period ago.
This makes the system work even when the game is closed.

Is perhaps not the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: Using PlayerPrefs system is more efficient and easy than trying to create 24-hour delay, just save the date and check the time difference.

Comment: @NittbaurS How do i go about this please?

Comment: I just tried this and it should work like this.

`string sOldDate;
    void Start()
    {

        sOldDate = PlayerPrefs.GetString("OldDate");
    }

    float fInc = 0f;
    void Update()
    {
        fInc+=Time.deltaTime;
        if (fInc>10) // Check every 10 seconds
        {
            fInc=0;
            System.DateTime dOldTime = System.DateTime.Parse(sOldDate);
            if(System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(dOldTime).TotalDays>1)
            {
                //Spawn stuff
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: However, you still have to keep in mind that the current value in PlayerPrefs does not have a value yet and you still have to assign it at some time --> DateTime.Now in PlayerPrefs